# App crashing when launching Unity - Does not crash when testing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c++, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

The app I developed works great when testing using Android Studio. But after publishing on the google play store is having issues.

The app has multiple pages. One of the pages launches an AR image tracking function using Unity with the click of a button. No issues at all when adding the app to my phone from Android Studio, everything works fine. But when downloaded from the Google Play store it crashes immediately when clicking the button to launch unity.

I'm a new Android Developer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Logcat - https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9x5dat31z95c4r/Logcat.rtf?dl=0

App - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ppas.augmented_reality

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2021-07-06 16:08:00.328 17795-17795/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 17795 (gmented_reality), pid 17795 (gmented_reality)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.363 17831-17831/? I/crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
2021-07-06 16:08:00.363 906-906/? I/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 17795
2021-07-06 16:08:00.363 17831-17831/? I/crash_dump64: performing dump of process 17795 (target tid = 17795)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sunfish/sunfish:11/RQ1A.210105.002/6985033:user/release-keys'
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: Revision: 'MP1.0'
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2021-07-06 16:08:00-0700
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: pid: 17795, tid: 17795, name: gmented_reality  >>> com.ppas.augmented_reality <<<
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10266
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'JNI FatalError called: com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer'
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000004583  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007ffceb1240
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:     x4  00000078ab720030  x5  00000078ab720030  x6  00000078ab720030  x7  00000078ab720030
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  4ca3e42badb83384  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffffc0fffffbdf
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000189917afcd3b  x14 001347d08f947541  x15 000000000d4e04f6
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:     x16 000000793bd0fc80  x17 000000793bcf1870  x18 00000000a174aa29  x19 0000000000004583
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000000000004583  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 00000076ab0b0fec  x23 0000000000000002
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:     x24 00000076ab090e77  x25 0000000000000001  x26 00000076ab0a7d99  x27 00000076ab6ac000
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:     x28 b4000076cb70d4b0  x29 0000007ffceb12c0
2021-07-06 16:08:00.371 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:     lr  000000793bca52a0  sp  0000007ffceb1220  pc  000000793bca52cc  pst 0000000000000000
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 000000000004e2cc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 95f68a34fdf7b31f42d3f811d5d88f58)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 000000000055bc54  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2308) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 0000000000013978  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76) (BuildId: 7f81cc97d60164bfae3b52a2cd822f20)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 0000000000012fa4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+320) (BuildId: 7f81cc97d60164bfae3b52a2cd822f20)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 00000000003983c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::FatalError(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+196) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0000000000217a9c  /data/app/~~TAMWGd-14TfFKvErTWaL9A==/com.ppas.augmented_reality-NXlM0L8oki0SgHTZyp6iyw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libunity.so (offset 0x2a04000) (JNI_OnLoad+60) (BuildId: 74ae5954e0e3bd5992fe1dd40d0f9a40d53b59af)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00000000000009ec  /data/app/~~TAMWGd-14TfFKvErTWaL9A==/com.ppas.augmented_reality-NXlM0L8oki0SgHTZyp6iyw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmain.so (offset 0x2a02000) (BuildId: dfeaba3b824754f525aa58ae8824762012ba7da7)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000000000000a0bc  /data/app/~~TAMWGd-14TfFKvErTWaL9A==/com.ppas.augmented_reality-NXlM0L8oki0SgHTZyp6iyw==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+172)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 000000000031830c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 000000000030e638  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 000000000067e070  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+548) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 00000000000fdbd4  /data/app/~~TAMWGd-14TfFKvErTWaL9A==/com.ppas.augmented_reality-NXlM0L8oki0SgHTZyp6iyw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<init>+332)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 000000000067da34  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1248) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 00000000000d4408  /data/app/~~TAMWGd-14TfFKvErTWaL9A==/com.ppas.augmented_reality-NXlM0L8oki0SgHTZyp6iyw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.PremierPools.ARAndroid.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate+60)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 0000000000305c34  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.4023174618862212076)+268) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 0000000000669e20  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 00000000005badec  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.Activity.performCreate+492) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #22 pc 000000000031fe80  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate+80) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #23 pc 00000000003fcba4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity+2356) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #24 pc 000000000040316c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity+556) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #25 pc 00000000005c7c34  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute+404) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #26 pc 000000000034b900  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks+560) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #27 pc 000000000034b650  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute+752) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #28 pc 00000000003e8618  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+536) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #29 pc 0000000000637484  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+180) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #30 pc 000000000063a97c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1516) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #31 pc 00000000003fbf90  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+752) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #32 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #33 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #34 pc 000000000055431c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1364) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #35 pc 00000000004d3b28  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #36 pc 00000000000896f4  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+180) (BuildId: ceb5e62f6d91c45ea99526daec5879eba39c6a54)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #37 pc 000000000088e588  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+136) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #38 pc 0000000000896cb8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2280) (BuildId: a72f300fea6269434019b1c853585300e82fcf64)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #39 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #40 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #41 pc 0000000000552d58  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+448) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #42 pc 000000000055320c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #43 pc 000000000043811c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+656) (BuildId: c820164b0c64ea40f1abc53aaf588b44)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #44 pc 0000000000099424  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: 8511fb98bccbbe26c39afaafc8b62b8f)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #45 pc 00000000000a08b0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+836) (BuildId: 8511fb98bccbbe26c39afaafc8b62b8f)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #46 pc 0000000000003580  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1336) (BuildId: bdcc463a75a1be87eb0f7478ec16547d)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.564 17831-17831/? A/DEBUG:       #47 pc 000000000004988c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108) (BuildId: 95f68a34fdf7b31f42d3f811d5d88f58)
2021-07-06 16:08:00.689 906-906/? E/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_10
```

Answer (score -1):

It happens because of some errors you should check the logcat where it will show error you can correct it .

Comment: Here is the logcat, any ideas? - https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9x5dat31z95c4r/Logcat.rtf?dl=0